# Reversi move checker

Tags: c#, game

I have this method to check if a move is possible in Reversi. The method works as it should, but it doesn't feel right for some reason. It feels very repetitive. I have tried to make it less repetitive by splitting it up in other methods, but that didn't make it any better.

```
public bool MovePossible(int y, int x)
{
    //check if position is in field
    if (y > 7 || x > 7 || y < 0 || x < 0) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }

    //check if spot is not occupied
    if(Bord[y, x] != Color.None)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //get color of current turn
    Color color = InTurn;

    //set oppesite color
    Color oppositeColor = Color.Black;
    if (color == Color.Black) oppositeColor = Color.White;

    //check: X, Y + 1
    if (y + 1 <= 7)
    {
        if(Bord[y + 1, x] == oppositeColor)
        {
            for (int i = y + 2; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                if(Bord[i, x] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X, Y - 1
    if (y - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if (Bord[y - 1, x] == oppositeColor)
        {
            for (int i = y - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Bord[i, x] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X + 1, Y
    if (x + 1 <= 7)
    {
        if (Bord[y, x + 1] == oppositeColor)
        {
            for (int i = x + 2; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                if (Bord[y, i] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X - 1, Y
    if (x - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if (Bord[y, x - 1] == oppositeColor)
        {
            for (int i = x - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Bord[y, i] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X + 1, Y + 1
    if (y + 1 <= 7 && x + 1 <= 7)
    {
        if (Bord[y + 1, x + 1] == oppositeColor)
        {
            var i = y + 2;
            var j = x + 2;

            while (i <= 7 && j <= 7)
            {
                if (Bord[i, j] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X - 1, Y - 1
    if (y - 1 >= 0 && x - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if (Bord[y - 1, x - 1] == oppositeColor)
        {
            var i = y - 2;
            var j = x - 2;

            while (i >= 0 && j >= 0)
            {
                if (Bord[i, j] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                i--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X - 1, Y + 1
    if (y + 1 <= 7 && x - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if (Bord[y + 1, x - 1] == oppositeColor)
        {
            var i = y + 2;
            var j = x - 2;

            while(i <= 7 && j >= 0)
            {
                if (Bord[i, j] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    //check: X + 1, Y - 1
    if (x + 1 <= 7 && y - 1 >= 0)
    {
        if (Bord[y - 1, x + 1] == oppositeColor)
        {
            var i = y - 2;
            var j = x + 2;

            while (i >= 0 && j <= 7)
            {
                if (Bord[i, j] == color)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                i--;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I would like to get some feedback on my code and how I can improve on it being less repetitive.

EDIT:

What is the code supposed to do?

The method has to check if a disk can be placed on a grid. It is part of the game Othello (or Reversi). The method has to return true when:

- Y and x are within the field (so between 0 and 7)
- The spot cannot be occupied
- Y and x has a neighbor with the opposite color. For example: I want to place a black disk on `3, 3`, either one or more of the following coordinates has to be white: `2, 2`, `2, 3`, `2, 4`, `3, 2`, `3, 4`, `4, 2`, `4, 3`, `4, 4`.
- The disk from the opposite color has to be surrounded.

An example:

```
         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

     0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
     1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     2   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     3   0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0
     4   0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0
     5   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     6   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     7   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to place a white(1) disk at Y: 2, X: 3. That's valid because the spot is empty, it's next to a black(2) disk and the black disk is now surrounded. When the disk is placed the grid looks like this:

```
         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

     0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
     1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     2   0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
     3   0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0
     4   0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0
     5   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     6   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     7   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Because the black disk is now surrounded by the white disks the disk becomes a white disk (the one at `3, 3`), but changing the disk happens in another function and is not important for the question.

Another example:

```
         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

     0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
     1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     2   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     3   0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0
     4   0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
     5   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
     6   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     7   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Placing a white(1) disk at Y: 4, X: 5 is not valid. It is next to a black(2) disk, but the black disk won't be surrounded, so it's not valid. Y: 2, X: 2 would be a valid move because the black disk at Y: 3, X: 3 is surrounded by Y: 2, X: 2 and Y 4 and X: 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't checked whether your logic following the `//check: X, Y + 1` comments is correct, but it can be refactored as follows. You're basically checking 8 directions (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW), each uniquely identified by a `dx` and a `dy` between -1 and 1. You need to exclude the case where `dx` and `dy` are both 0.

```
dx    -1 0 +1
dy -1 NW N NE
    0  W .  E
   +1 SW S SE
```

That would give code like this:

```
for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
    for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0)
            continue;

        if (x + dx < 0 || x + dx > 7 || y + dy < 0 || y + dy > 7)
            continue;

        if (Bord[y + dy, x + dx] != oppositeColor)
            continue;

        int i = 2;
        while (i <= 7)
        {
            if (x + i * dx < 0 || x + i * dx > 7 || y + i * dy < 0 || y + i * dy > 7)
                break;
            if (Bord[y + i * dy, x + i * dx] == Color.None)
                break;
            if (Bord[y + i * dy, x + i * dx] == color)
            {
                return true;            
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! this looks way better and seems totally logical!